# react redux ui not re-rendering after state get updated

Tags: react-redux

I have a json array as date and I am trying to add an element in the array but my react component does not get rerendered:

```
export default function groupReducer(state = initialState , action){
    switch (action.type){
        case 'ADD_GROUP' :
            const newId = state.groups.length + 1;
            const newGroup = [{id : newId , name : action.text},{id : 12,name : 'myname'}];
            state.push(newGroup);
            return state

        default :
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You should provide more information than just code and a title...

Comment: i am new to redux I have json array as date I am trying to add a element in the array but my react component not get rerendering

Comment: Next time you should add this text to your question, for now I edited it for you. Your question need to be as clear and specific as possible.

Comment: I  know i am returning the same state so react can not find the change, but I dont know how to add my new object into the state and to return new state...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not advised to mutate the state directly under redux rather return a new state and add  the newGroup

Try this Remove
`state.push(newGroup)` and `return state`

and replace with `return { ...state, newGroup }`